# issue cloning repos from github

Tags: github, import, jupyter, git-clone, finrl

I'm trying to run the FinRL notebook [here](https://github.com/AI4Finance-Foundation/FinRL-Meta/blob/master/Demo_Plug_and_Play_with_DRL_Libraries.ipynb) but when I try to import the cloned libraries the finrl modules can't be found. I tried to check the file path where it said they were installed but I couldn't locate it in finder. (working on Mac)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By default if you clone a repository on Mac, it will be saved on the 'Macintosh HD' drive.
If not, try to find a folder named 'GitHub' on your 'Macintosh HD' drive.

```
MacintoshHD/Users/Mac
```

Or the issue might be that you never initialized a new local repository.

If that is the case, the below commands should work :-

```
git init

git clone https://github.com/AI4Finance-Foundation/FinRL-Meta.git
```